# How do i create a user (not hard-coded) to a pre-existing group and prompt the new user to enter his new password?

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible and this is a project i am working on. so far the below code is what i put together. This code works however, the password does not register and when i log in with the new user i created. it says authentication failure. Please help

```
---
- hosts: box432
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
   - name: 'creating user with password'
     prompt: 'enter password for user'
     private: yes
     encrypt: sha512_crypt
     confirm: yes
     salt_size: 7
  tasks:
  -  pause: prompt="enter user name"
     register: user_name
  -  name: "Print"
     debug: msg="{{ user_name }}"
  -  name: updating user password
     become: true
     user:
        name: "{{ user_name }}"
        state: present
        groups: stackflow
```

Comment: Please explain what does this question have to do with "*a tablet computer made by Research In Motion.*" You tagged it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `name` in `vars_prompt` is not an arbitrary comment, but the name of the variable to be set, so this section should be:

```
vars_prompt:
  - name: "provided_password"
    prompt: "enter password for user"
    private: yes
    encrypt: sha512_crypt
    confirm: yes
    salt_size: 7
```

Secondly, in your code you are not even trying to use that variable. You should provide the value in the `password` argument:

```
- name: updating user password
  become: true
  user:
    name: "{{ user_name }}"
    password: "{{ provided_password }}"
    state: present
    groups: stackflow
```